# Replace iteration's fetch to BULK COLLECT

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor

There is an object type and table consists of that objects. 
So here we go:

```
create or replace type lpu.someobj_o as object
(      
  name VARCHAR2(75),     
  enroll_date DATE,
  id NUMBER(12)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lpu."SOMEOBJ_T" IS TABLE OF someobj_o;
```

There's also PL/SQL function that works in common [ETL principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). Here is piece of code function:

```
  for some_cursor_rec in some_cursor(startTime, recordInterval) loop
  open some_cur2(some_cursor_rec.name, some_cursor_rec.id);
  fetch some_cur2 into some_cursor_rec2;
  if some_cur2%rowcount > 0 then
    loop
      pipe row (
        lpu.someobj_o(
        id => some_cursor_rec2.id, 
        name => some_cursor_rec2.name, 
        enroll_date => some_cursor_rec2.enroll_date
      )
      );
      fetch some_cur2 into some_cursor_rec2;
      exit when some_cur2%notfound;
    end loop;      
  end if;
  close some_cur2;
end loop;
```

Ok, so the issue is small performance. How can I increase speed of completing of this function? I have read that `BULK COLLECT` should improve performance. But how can I use it in my case? I have tried `BULK COLLECT` but it gave me error that type of collection is wrong. 
Thanks in advance! Really hope for your help!

Comment: `FETCH` Statement with `BULK COLLECT` Clause? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/tuning.htm#BCGGAGIF

Comment: I'm a little skeptical about the benefit of using `bulk collect` in a pipelined function. Even if you load several rows at once, you still can only pipe one of them to the output at a time. For that matter, unless there's significantly more processing going on in the function, I'd have to question why you're using a pipelined function in the first place.

Comment: I can refuse from pipelined functions if it needs for better performance. Do you recommend that for me?

Answer (score 4):

If performance is your concern, then you should start looking at combining your two cursors.

Current you are executing the query in the some_cursor once, and you are **executing the query in cursor some_cur2 as many times as there are rows selected in the first query**. And that's highly likely your performance bottleneck.

If you combine the two queries to one query and do a cursor for loop (which executes the query only once), then you'll automatically be bulk fetching 100 rows at a time, so there probably won't be a real need to manually convert it to do bulk fetching.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: I have tried one complicated cursor before. And I was getting some performance down-grade with just one cursor. Function finished execution in about 1 second. Now (with two cursors) we have about 0,1 second to go. First cursor would bring about 5-15 records and seconds cursor returns about 40-50 records for each first cursor's record. Any advices, please?

Comment: My advice is to post the two cursors and your one cursor, and their plans so we can have a look at them. You can follow the advice in this post: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1812597

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example how to use `bulk collect into` with an object type.

```
create or replace type someobj_o as object
(      
  name varchar2(75),     
  enroll_date date,
  id number(12)
);
/

create or replace type someobj_t is table of someobj_o;
/

create table someobj_table of someobj_o;

insert into someobj_table values(someobj_o('Joe', current_date, 100));
insert into someobj_table values(someobj_o('Jack', current_date, 101));
insert into someobj_table values(someobj_o('John', current_date, 102));

declare
  v_objs someobj_t;
begin
  select someobj_o(name, enroll_date, id)
    bulk collect into v_objs
    from someobj_table;

  dbms_output.put_line('number of objects in a collection = ' || v_objs.count);
end;
/
```

---

**Update**

The same than above with a cursor:

```
declare
  type objcur_t is ref cursor;
  v_objcur objcur_t;
  v_objs someobj_t;
begin
  open v_objcur for
    select someobj_o(name, enroll_date, id)
    from someobj_table;

  fetch v_objcur bulk collect into v_objs;

  close v_objcur;

  dbms_output.put_line('number of objects in a collection = ' || v_objs.count);
end;
/
```

Comment: I saw similar example in the Web. But I exactly need to fill `someobj_table` from cursor with `BULK COLLECT INTO`. How can I get this working?

Comment: @kseen: works perfectly on my Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 when I cut and paste the code to SQLPLUS. What Oracle version you are running ?